# What does this syntax for regular expressions mean?

Tags: java, regex

Can someone tell me what the regular expression in the following Java code snippet means:

```
String someString = …;
someString.matches("^\\d{5}-\\d{4}$");
```

Comment: The code you have posted is not legal Java. Is it impossible for you to actually try out this code?

Comment: Are you sure it is not `"\\d{5}-\\d{4}$"`?

Comment: http://ideone.com/d3ofo   --- it's that simple to try it out.

Comment: I'm sorry, @Bergi you're right, its actually "^\\d{5}-\\d{4}$"

Answer (score 0):

This will match 5 decimal numbers at the beginning of the string, followed by a dash, followed by 4 decimal numbers at the end.

```
^ = Beginning of string
\d{n} = Match n decimal numbers
$ = End of string
```

Answer (score 0):

From http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

five digits, a dash, and then four more digits...nothing else

Answer (score 0):

`^` means beginning of line.

`\d{5}` means five digits.

`-` literally means "-"

`\d{4}` means four digits.

`$` means end of line.

So it's looking for a sequence of five digits followed by a sequence of four digits, seperated by a dash and that is the only thing on the line.

Example:

> 12345-6789